# Drupal 8 - Repeatable Form Fields

Tags: forms, drupal, module, field

I am looking to build a module in Drupal 8 after having used Joomla. The issue I'm having is that I can't seem to find a way to configure additional fields where required. Similar to [this method](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type) in Joomla if possible so that I can add more of the same fields e.g multiple contact number boxes.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to use [Paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) instead of field collection for Drupal 8 projects.

Comment: Give an example (code) of how you think this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check
[Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)
It's drupal entity based module that allow you to create repeater fields.
You can create group of fields and embed them into existing content types.

example:

> Your Collection:
>
> Item 1:
>
> - title
> - body
> - image
>
> Item 2:
>
> - title
> - body
> - image
>
> Add another item

Comment: Przemek is actually right. Repeater fields in Drupal 7 does the job similar to ACF Repeater fields in Wordpress. Thanks for helping me finding the wordpress analogue for Drupal!